# canvas is too tall

Tags: css, canvas, height

My CSS:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
canvas
{
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
html
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

As you can see, my `body` is as tall/wide as the window's available height/width respectively. My `canvas` has 100% height/width, and it seems like it should be the height and width of the inside of the window. But it isn't. It's a few pixels taller, and a scrollbar appears. Why is this? Can I make it work somehow? I don't think the `canvas` has any padding or anything. This occurs in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need:

```
canvas { display: block; }
```

since canvas is an inline element, like `img`.

Inline elements get some "leading" underneath, just like the surrounding text does.

Answer (score 0):

<del>The browser may be getting confused: With the scrollbars, the canvas is too big to fit. Without them, it fits.</del>

Ignore that, complete nonsense. `<canvas>` is an inline element, so it suffers the same problems as images. Add `verical-align:bottom`, or try this instead:

```
canvas {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;
}
```